# Writing/reading a file in binary mode in Clisp

Tags: file-io, lisp, common-lisp, clisp, line-endings

I'm writing this program that's supposed to read from a file, do some stuff with the content and write to an output file preserving the original line endings. If the file has `CRLF` endings, the output file should also have that. My problem is in writing the line ending especially with the `CLISP` implementation(it works with `gcl`). When I try to write a linefeed character(`LF`), the file ends up having `CRLF` endings. I'm guessing this is something to do with `CLISP`'s implementation.
I need a way to `write the file in binary mode` like in other langauages. The standard I/O functions in the specification only take an optional stream name and the content to be written.

You can reproduce that behaviour with something like this:

```
(with-open-file (out-file "test.dat" :direction :output)
  (setf ending #\linefeed)
  (princ "First Line" out-file)
  (write-char ending out-file)
  (princ "Second Line" out-file)
  (write-char ending out-file)
  (princ "Second Line" out-file))
```

I need a solution that works in windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify [`:EXTERNAL-FORMAT`](http://clisp.org/impnotes/open.html#extfmt) argument, mentioning the [line terminator mode](http://clisp.org/impnotes/encoding.html#newline):

```
(with-open-file (out-file "test.dat" :direction :output :external-format :unix)
  ...)
```

The external format defaults to `:dos` on windows because that is the standard on Microsoft systems.

Note that you do *not* want binary mode if you are actually writing text. In Common Lisp (as opposed to C and Emacs Lisp), there is a very clear separation between [binary i/o](http://clisp.org/impnotes/bin-io.html) (reading and writing `byte`s) and text i/o (reaching and writing [`character`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_ch.htm)s), just like a number is not a character and vice versa, even though characters have an integer [code](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_char_c.htm).

Comment: Why should reading in binary mode be slower for this case? And, unmaintainable how?

Comment: because you are reimplementing system functionality by hand. if you want to do that, use assembly :-)

Comment: hehe. I like this approach better; it's much simpler.